# AngularJS 2: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got this error when lauching my application. What am I making wrong?
I've already imported FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule package in my module.
I'm using Angular 2.4.9

**app.module.ts:**

```js
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { PainelComponent } from './painel/painel.component';

import { PainelModule } from './painel/painel.module';
import { SidebarModule } from './sidebar/sidebar.module';
import { FooterModule } from './shared/footer/footer.module';
import { NavbarModule} from './shared/navbar/navbar.module';

import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [
        BrowserModule,
        PainelModule,
        SidebarModule,
        NavbarModule,
        FooterModule,
        FormsModule,                               
        ReactiveFormsModule,      
        RouterModule.forRoot([])
    ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent, PainelComponent ],
    providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Console displays the follow:**

```html
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. (""for="">RA <span class="star">*</span></label><input type="text" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="myModel" />{{myModel}}</"): AlunoComponent@10:51 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import {Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    location: Location;
    constructor(location:Location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    ngOnInit(){
        $.getScript('dashboard.js');
    }
    public isMaps(path){
        var titlee = this.location.prepareExternalUrl(this.location.path());
        titlee = titlee.slice( 1 );
        if(path === titlee){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I was trying to do a test, so the HTML page is very simple

**HTML page:**

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label" for="">RA </label>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myModel" />{{myModel}}</div>
```

Comment: which version of Angular your are working. Can u also post the html ?

Comment: I'm using Angular 2.4.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a sample with the same version(**2.4.9**) of angular and it's working fine for me. I think you are not declared **myModel** property on your component

https://plnkr.co/edit/Hmq6bdXkeaK3HQ33WCXX?p=preview

```
<input [(ngModel)]="myModel" placeholder="">

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: "src/app.html"
})
export class App {
myModel:string="test";
    constructor() {

    }
}
```